# What is a zero order differential equation?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

So I was doing homework today and ran into a problem; it goes like this: Find a general zero order differential equation and give its solution.

So, I tried this:

> General zero order diffyq: d/dx(f(x)) = b(x) 
> Solution: f(x) =  ∫ b(x)dx + c

Isn't d/dx(f(x)) just dy/dx? Would some general zero order differential equation be f(x) = b(x)? Wouldn't the solution in that case be
 f(x) = b(x)? I've done the reading and think I may have missed something.
 
Any help is appreciated!
Hiefenhoomer

Comment: I have not come across Diff Eq of Zero Order. We generally have Positive Integer Order. We might abuse terminology to get Zero Order Diff Eq which has no Derivatives : Equation $y-2x+3=0$ Solution $y=2x-3$